# System does not boot after recent kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, asus

I did an apt-get dist-upgrade that installed a new kernel today.

Now my ASUS UX330U does not boot anymore. Fan, power LED and Caps Lock are on but screen is dark and there is nothing I can do anymore.

Booting from USB is not possible.

Looks like the System is severely damaged. :-(

Has anyone any idea?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release details, but just select an older kernel at the `grub` prompt and explore from there.  You've also not provided any useful details, did you try booting to recovery mode?  restricting boot to runlevel 1?removing 'quiet splash` etc (the runlevel 1/quiet splash you may not understand as somewhat technical sorry, but details are required esp. OS/release)

Comment: It does not get to the boot prompt anymore :/
Power- and CapsLock indicators are on immediately. Black screen, no response anymore.

Comment: No boot from external device possible.

And Sorry: It is Kubuntu 19.10

Comment: Do you see a vendor splash screen at power on? Can you enter your BIOS? Can you get to the GRUB menu? Can you boot to an older kernel?

Comment: @heynnema No, none of it. As I mentioned: Power and CapsLock are on constantly. No response to anything. Fan starts moderately and stays constant.
I can restart by pressing Power for ca. 15 sec. as often as I want. No change.
No idea, what this is.

I'll try to open it tomorrow, need a special tool for this. Maybe there is some way to reset the BIOS...

Comment: Do you have removable batteries? Is it under warranty?

Comment: Unfortunately not, needs to be opened. I don't have the necessary tool at hand.

But, does a kernel upgrade really modifies something in the BIOS?

Comment: If it's under warranty, don't open it yourself. If it's not under warranty, if you open it, unplug the internal battery, then hold down the power button for 15 seconds, then reconnect the battery and try to boot. You could contact ASUS Support and see if there's a way to recover.

Comment: See http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-zenbook-ux300-completely-dead-service-center-fixed-in-10m.807737/

Comment: @heinnema Alright! Your post sounds good! 

Thanks so far. I'll try this - in the hope that they won't close all the shops in Germany tomorrow... ;-)

I'll post the result here. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, keep me posted... but please do spell my name correctly so that I'll get a notification. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema Incredible, by miracle it solved itself over night by simply doing nothing. I decided to keep the notebook plugged in over night. this morning it started up.

Not as usual, because it showed the ASUS logo two times until it booted. (As if something was done in the background and performed a restart eventually).

I really wonder how this can happen. But whoever has an ASUS notebook that doesn't boot anymore with CapsLock and Power LED on: Try it by leaving it alone for one night. It will boot up again.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No, this is not true anymore.
Turning off and on again: Same situation....

Obviously the notebook is broken now.

Comment: @FelixRoske As we discussed earlier, unplug the AC, pull the internal battery connection, press the power key for 15 seconds. Or, try this... from a power off state, with AC connected, hold down the power button for 15 seconds, then retest. Report back.